# How to attach custom styles into zf2 forms

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

Maybe its obvious problem but could you please tell me how can I add custom css styles to forms created by standard view helpers in zend framework 2?

Im trying to attach some styles to forms created by ZfcUser

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assign the class-attribute :)

```
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'element_name',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'element_label'
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => 'element_type',
            'class'  => 'testing'
        )
    ));
```

Since you want to extend an existing form, you could either grab the Form and then `$form->get('elementname')->setAttribute('class','blubb');` or you overwrite the Service-Form from ZfCUser with your custom form that has all styles attached, given above example.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931834/zend-framework-2-form-element-decorators/20183694), maybe the Partial method is the flexible and light choice.

Comment: why use partials? just extend the already existing view helpers... they  exist for this reason