# How to customize checkbox group in Zend framework-2 form?

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

Actually I can not understand, how zend framework 2 generate HTML for a form element. For example,

```
$others = new Element\MultiCheckbox('others');
$others->setLabel('Others')
        ->setAttribute('name', 'others');
$others->setValueOptions(array(
    '1' => 'Contacts',
    '2' => 'Who viewd my profile'
));
```

This code generates -

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="others[]">Contacts</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="others[]">Who viewd my profile</label>
```

But I need to make the HTML as follows -

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="others[]"><label>Contacts</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="others[]"><label>Who viewd my profile</label>
```

So If I want to change the generated HTML, How can I do it?

Comment: This might help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931834/zend-framework-2-form-element-decorators

Comment: I have checked that, but still have not get solution for checkbox group. I can customize some, but can not do with checkbox group. When I write echo $this->formElement($elements['others']); it always generate those group of code.

Comment: perhaps this `$others->setAttribute('name', 'others')
        ->setLabel('Others');`

Comment: @Amir : No that is not, setlabel('Others') will set the label for entire checkbox group, and by default each checkbox of checkbox group generated inside each label. And that is the problem.

Comment: Actually , the result is the same in both format you mentioned. what is the difference for you, really?

Comment: @Amir Example: https://zf2-cn.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.element.multicheckbox.html. By default each value option will be inside label including checkbox, but I need to keep the value options label inside label or span or div and checkbox will outside of that. That is for CSS styling.

Comment: @TahminaKhatoon I mentioned this inside my answer: when writing HTML, it shouldn't even bother about styling. Maybe give an example of how you want to style your Element and we'd be able to help you out without modifying the DOM ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of Feature you would need to overwrite [`Zend\Form\View\Helper\MultiCheckbox`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormMultiCheckbox.php) or to be more precise the [`renderOptions()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormMultiCheckbox.php#L147) function of it.

You'd then let the `ViewHelperManager` know that `$this->formMultiCheckbox()` should invoke your very own `ViewHelper` to get the desired result.

However i want to mention that what you're trying to do is HIGHLY discouraged. Users should absolutely be able to click the label! IF you're going to change the markup, at least do it like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="others[]" id="cbOthers1"><label for="cbOthers2">Foo</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="others[]" id="cbOthers1"><label for="cbOthers2">Bar</label>
```

Never forget about the usability of your application! Another hint: having the CB inside the label automatically enables you a much wider audience as far as browser support with styling is concerned! Then again though, all up to you. You will have to write yourself your own `ViewHelper` anyways.

**PS:** your `ViewHelper` would be pretty easy, you'll only need to overwrite [those lines](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormMultiCheckbox.php#L227-L236) to the following:

```
  switch ($labelPosition) {
     case self::LABEL_PREPEND:
        $template  = $labelOpen . '%s'. $labelClose .'%s';
        $markup    = sprintf($template, $label, $input);
     break;
     case self::LABEL_APPEND:
     default:
        $template  = '%s' . $labelOpen . '%s'. $labelClose;
        $markup    = sprintf($template, $input, $label);
      break;
 }
```